# Regex : adding a number before specific number pattern found

Tags: regex

I'm trying to add a number `9` before a specific pattern in a file containing many EANs, like this example :

```
7,82897E+11 50 MATCHS DE HOCKEY 39,95   23,97   40  1   0   0
7,82924E+11 EINSTEIN    34,95   20,97   40  1   0   0
15  BEAUX LIVRES & SCIENCE  94,85   56,91   40  3   0   0
7,82101E+11 SCIENCE  COMME VOUS NE L'AVEZ   34,95   20,97   40  1   0   0
```

I'm specifically searching for EANs (which are at the begining of data line) who starts with either `7,8` or `7,9` and I must add a 9 before those numbers.

So the pattern will look like `9,78xxx` or `9,79xxx` after the replacement.

I used this regexp to find those strings:

```
\t\t[7][,][8|9]
```

The two `\t\t` serves me to not replace the number AFTER the first one in the line.

I was thinking of this : `\t\t[9],[7][8|9]` but the last part `[8|9]` is not working, as I expected... I dont know how to just place the number found (8 or 9)...

Hope this is possible to do!

Thanks for any help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: the character class `[89]` does not need the alternation `|`.

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, you could use a group reference, such as `\1` or `\2`. Or just use two regex: one for 7.8 and one for 7.9

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex based replacement:

```
^([ \t]*)7,([89])
```

And replace with `${1}9,7$2` (or just `$19,7$2` if it is JavaScript, `\g<1>9,7\2` in Python, `\19,7\2` in POSIX (because POSIX BRE only supports up to 9 backreferences), or `\019,7\2` in some weird regex flavors).

Instead of `[ \t]`, you can use `\s` shorthand character class if it is supported.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP0qH8/2)

Also please note that `[8|9]` matches 1 symbol: `8`, `|` or `9`. The pipe character loses its special meaning inside a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `([ \t]*)` - (Group 1) zero or more spaces or tabs
- `7,`  - a sequence of characters `7,`
- `([89])` - (Group 2) either `8` or `9`.

If you need to match the beginning of the lines, you can either use a multiline flag, or inline version of it, or a special flag.

Comment: Do you need to capture the whitespace?

Comment: If the whitespace must be kept in the output, I need to capture the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your search pattern could be

`/^([\t]*)([7][,])([8|9])/`

the replacement could be:

`$19,7$3`

this will modify your sample from

7,82897E+11 50 MATCHS DE HOCKEY 39,95   23,97

to:

9,782897E+11 50 MATCHS DE HOCKEY 39,95   23,97

What it does:

a) the search:

it splits the search into three groupsmarked by the `(..)`

1) the beginning of the line

2) does the string starts with **7,**

3) is it followed either by **8** or **9**

the in the subtitution it adds the string `9,7` and by refering to the third group using `$3`it adds either 8 or 9. The rest of the string stays untouched.